# Less than / Less than or equal operator doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, html

Very simple slider with setInteval function. Please clear for me if there is some rule for this situation. I have 5 slides, only 3 of them get shown, then slider goes to "margin-left" = "0" position, without showing the last 2 slides. **I write in my code to return to "margin-left" = "0" only after "margin-left" reaches "2000px" or more** (each slide is 500px, I have 5 slides). **In other words, slider goes back after reaching "1000px" "margin", although I write "2000px" or more.**

My html is 
500px < div >; 2500px < ul > inside < div >; 5 pieces of 500px < li > inside < ul >, I do not use overflow:hidden to show what happens.

```
<style>
    #container {
        height: 400px;
        border: 4px solid red;
    }

        #container ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            height: 100%;
            padding: 0px;
            display: flex;
            transition: all 1s ease
        }

            #container ul li {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%
            }

                #container ul li:nth-child(1) {
                    background-color: yellow;
                    opacity: 0.5;
                }

                #container ul li:nth-child(2) {
                    background-color: green;
                    opacity: 0.5
                }

                #container ul li:nth-child(3) {
                    background-color: red;
                    opacity: 0.5
                }

                #container ul li:nth-child(4) {
                    background-color: teal;
                    opacity: 0.5
                }

                #container ul li:nth-child(5) {
                    background-color: grey;
                    opacity: 0.5
                }
</style>
<body>
    <div id="container" style="width:500px;">
        <ul style="margin:0px; width:2500px;">
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

Javascript side:

```
<script>
    ul_list = document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];
    li_list = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
    li_width = parseFloat(document.getElementById("container").style.width);
    el_width = li_width;
    li_array = Array.prototype.slice.call(li_list, 0);

    function carousel() {
        /*THIS IS MY PROBLEM, return to marginLeft = 0 when marginLeft = -2000px or more,
       in reality it executes if statement when -1000px is reached*/
        if (ul_list.style.marginLeft <= -((li_width * li_array.length) - li_width) + "px") {
            ul_list.style.marginLeft = 0 + "px";
            el_width = li_width;
        }
        else {
            ul_list.style.marginLeft = -el_width + "px";
            el_width += li_width;
        }
    }

    function call() {
        call_carousel = setInterval(carousel, 3000);
    }
    call();
</script>
```

Comment: Just from a quick glance, you are comparing strings there by adding the "px". "-2000" is greater than "-1000" as a string because it searches for the first nonidentical char in the string and then takes its index. "2" > "1". Maybe that's already your issue. Try stripping the px and do a parseInt() on the result.

Comment: Why should comparing two strings work?

Comment: I definitely overlooked it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic does not work because the value returned by the ".marginLeft" call is a string.

Try this:

```
var ulMarginLeft = parseInt(ul_list.style.marginLeft);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a new utility function like:

```
function getInt(value) {
  return parseInt(value.match(/\d+/)[0]);
}
```

and then modify the comparison like:

```
var marginLeft = getInt(ul_list.style.marginLeft);
var arrayMargin = getInt((li_width * li_array.length) - li_width) * -1;

// Check the values once in console for debugging
console.log( marginLeft, arrayMargin)

if (marginLeft <= arrayMargin ) {
  // Your code here....
}
```